# R: loop won't run due to a seq.default error

Tags: r, for-loop, seq, auc

I am trying to calculate the area under the curve for every 10ms of a short piece of EEG wave. To first practice this I made a small dataset to run the `auc` (from package `{flux}`) function on.

```
x <- seq(1:10)
y <- c(0:4,5:1)
df <- data.frame(x,y)
attach(df)
plot(x,y)

for (i in 1:10){
  x1 <- c(i,(i+1))
  y1 <- c(subset(y, x == i),subset(y, x == (i+1)))
auc(x1,y1,thresh = 0)
rm(y1,x1,i)
}
```

The loop should try to subset two data points from each variable and then run a `auc` over those data points. However, when running the loop, I get this error:
`Error in seq.default(x[1], x[2], length.out = dens) : 'to' must be a finite number`

When I run the `subset` and `auc` code outside of the loop, it works no problem. Can anyone tell me what's going wrong in the loop?

Comment: This is the problem: subset(y, x == (i+1)) when i == 10

Comment: for i=10 i+1=11, out of your `df`

Comment: I see, how would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating the question. It's not because of the control statement (for loop), the error gets thrown precisely when i=10 -- because the length of your x-coords and y-coords vectors are different. Specifically c(10,11) vs c(1). But you have no point at x=11 !

just stop the loop early, at the appropriate time

Comment: I updated my question, the `auc` function is from the package `{flux}`  [link](https://artax.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/r-help/library/flux/html/auc.html)